# Set mat-table to use remaining space on screen with scrollbar

Tags: css, angular-material, angular7, mat-table

I have an application composed by this vertical structure:a navbar, a search section and table with the results.
Each of these tree elements take up the space it needs without using fixed sizes. More over the search section has hidden sub-sections so it's size can change over time.

What I'm trying to do is this: I would like these three sections to independently adjust their height to occupy all the space avaible. But since I can have a lot of results on the table this one needs to have, eventually, a vertical scrollbar. So the only scroolbar I want to see is in the table's results section.

If I set

> overflow: auto

on the global CSS I see a global scrollbar if the table has too many results.

How can I force the table to use the remaining space on screen and show a scrollbar when it needs to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use CSS with Flexbox to make the table fill up the remaining screen space by setting the `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` properties appropriately on your navbar, search, and table sections. Then use an absolutely positioned div with `overflow: auto` to wrap your table.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="navbar"></div>
    <div id="search"></div>
    <div id="table">
        <div id="table-container">
            <!-- Table goes here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
}

#navbar {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
}

#search {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

#table {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#table-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

#table-container table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

And for bonus points, add `position: sticky` to pin the table header on scroll:

```
.mat-header-row th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Stackblitz demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ykwfsy

Comment: Thanks, it's working! Is possible to have the scrollbar only inside the table without the table header?

Comment: I think it's probably possible but all of the solutions I've seen are incredibly ugly. If you were hand-coding the table and could move the HTML around, it would be easier, but to do it with a mat-table would be a lot of work—you would basically have to override all the default styles. Is pinning the table header not sufficient, or is there another reason you'd like to just scroll the table body?

Comment: If you're asking about the scroll bar on the page in the Stackblitz, that's related to the use of `height: 100vh;`. Adding `body { margin: 0; }` and `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` should fix it.

Comment: Here is a [picture](https://i.imgur.com/nI4PRVI.png) showing what I mean. I'd like to keep only the table's scroll bar; and get rid of the 'external' scroll bar. +1 by the way.

Comment: Ah, you just need to move those 2 CSS rules up into styles.css so it will affect the entire HTML page. The CSS styling in app.component.css will only affect the HTML in app.component.html.

Comment: It worked. If I couldn't edit the global CSS (so to not affect other components), would there be another way?

Comment: Hmm you can try tweaking the height of the container in the app component CSS, e.g. `#container { height: calc(100vh - 16px); }` (modify the "16px" value as needed). That will allow you to avoid the use of `* { box-sizing: border-box; }`.